# file_get_contents fails with "getaddrinfo failed: no address associated with hostname"

Tags: php, dns, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get the page from another host. I do as hph manual says:

```
    $page = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
    echo $page;
```

But it fails and in apache log i get the following:

```
[Mon Oct 12 18:58:47.676454 2015] [:error] [pid 2971] [client 127.0.0.1:49434] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname in /var/www/html/digest/ftry.php on line 2
[Mon Oct 12 18:58:47.704659 2015] [:error] [pid 2971] [client 127.0.0.1:49434] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www.example.com/): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname in /var/www/html/digest/ftry.php on line 2
```

While trying to figure out the reason of failure, I checked what `nslookup` says. When I run `nslookup http://www.example.com/` it answers something like that:

```
nslookup http://www.example.com/
Server:         94.242.57.130
Address:        94.242.57.130#53

** server can't find http://www.example.com/: NXDOMAIN
```

When I remove `http://` from domain name it works fine, returns ip. But when I try to get file with `file_get_contents` without `http://`, it looks for the file in the local filesystem (and it's how it's supposed to be).

I've checked `phpinfo`, `allow_url_fopen` is `On` on both local and master levels. I've set the nameserver in my `resolv.conf` to `94.242.57.130` (nearest public dns).

Comment: Here is some code to show you what php is getting for dns much like nslookup. 
 $dnsrecs = dns_get_record('www.example.com');
 foreach($dnsrecs as $dnsrec){
    foreach($dnsrec as $label=>$val){
     echo $label.':'. $val . '<br>';
    }
 }

Comment: @JasonK That was interest, `dns_get_record` returned the actual record, but the old failure in `file_get_contents` still continues. I've decided to switch to `curl`.

Comment: Please note that `nslookup` expects a host name like www.example.com, not leaded by any schema such as https://. The correct use is `nslookup www.example.com`.

Comment: @BurninLeo The question was not about nslookup itself. As you can see from my investigations, I know, how to use nslookup. The question was about how to make file_get_contents get file by URL in web, as without explicit shema it looks in local filesystem, but with "http://" it fails to get adress because of nslookup syntax.

Comment: @ba3a: Yes, my comment was only for others not to step over the (wrong) nslookup syntax (like I did) when searching for "getaddinfo failed" solutions. Finally, using nslookup to trace the source of the problem is a good idea....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `allow_url_fopen` is disabled on you `php.ini`, that's why `file_get_contents` isn't working.
Try using [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/";
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $page;
```

Comment: As I have already written, I've checked `phpinfo` and `allow_url_fopen` is `On`. I think I'll have to switch to `curl`, but `file_get_contents` is recomended in all manuals, so I'd like to use it if it was possible.

Comment: The dns server may have some issues, try using google dns servers to test if the problem is that, `8.8.8.8` and `4.4.4.4`

Comment: @pedro.. that would be 8.8.4.4.

Comment: Correct! My bad, although, I use my own dns server based on root servers. Tks for pointing that!

Comment: I am using windows 10 with Xampp and facing the same issue. Kindly suggest me where to add `8.8.4.4` Thanks.

Comment: On the connection properties.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue for `file_get_contents` even while `allow_url_fopen` is on. Also as CURL have a similar problem with the host.

Here is how the site owner solved this:

" Needed to add an extra A record to Directadmin, www was presented but not without www:

example.com. A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "