# PHP get_file_contents() returns "no address associated with hostname"

Tags: php, http, curl, nginx, php-5.5

PHP-FPM seems to have issues with DNS occasionally, as recently also reported in [DNS not working in PHP (but does in general)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42926060/dns-not-working-in-php-but-does-in-general). As the issue seems more complex than described in the other question, I'd like to elaborate on the problem a bit more.

In line with the cited question, restarting PHP_FPM helps:

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

But only for a while, it seems.

---

My PHP script contacts a second server via `file_get_contents()`, which has worked fine ... until yesterday. For a simple request such as

```
file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
```

I get an error "No address associated with hostname".

```
file_get_contents(http://www.example.com/): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname
```

When trying the same with `curl`, the error is similar:

```
Could not resolve host: www.example.com
```

Yes, I actually tested this with www.example.com to exclude the server as source of error.

When doing a `nslookup`, using the same server that also runs PHP, everything seems okay:

```
$ nslookup www.example.com
Server:         xx.xx.xx.100
Address:        xx.xx.xx.100#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   www.example.com
Address: 93.184.216.34
```

I am using PHP 5.5.9 via PHP-FPM on a nginx server. The error logs of PHP5-FPM, nginx, and the syslog do not contain any more information about this issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents fails with "getaddrinfo failed: no address associated with hostname"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33085948/file-get-contents-fails-with-getaddrinfo-failed-no-address-associated-with-hos)

Comment: No, probably no duplicate. I had already commented on that question, but the problem seemed to be a different there (also it wasn't figured out in that question from 2012).

Comment: this would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42956679/wordpress-wp-remote-post-gives-curl-error-6-could-not-resolve-host/42957214#42957214

Comment: A security fix in Ubuntu that cause the trouble... I would never have found that, thank you so much! If that is the cause, restarting the service (after an update) should really be the solution.